# 301 Redirect htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to do a 301 redirect for my site URL's like  http://example.com/old-folder/allhtmlfiles.html to  http://example.com/new-folder/allhtmlfiles.html.

All html files under old-folder should be accessible with the /new-folder/

How can  I do this, I tried some solutions I found here but they were  giving me 404 errors.

Thanks for your help.

Suzy Matts

---

I changed my .htaccess accordingly but does'nt work. 
I think I had not clearly mentioned the slug change in my previous question.

This was the actual previous link in this wordpress site,

http://dland.in/sale/land-in-madikeri-karnataka-state-india-1750-acre/

and now the folder name has changed and this is the new link

http://dland.in/kerala-real-estate-sale/land-in-madikeri-karnataka-state-india-1750-acre/

**the second slug (land-in-madikeri-karnataka-state-india-1750-acre) can be any**

so I want to get a 301 redirect to the new link.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: show us some solutions you tried please

Comment: @yazmat this is .htaccess as of now... i had tried different ones and i havent noted down them...some brought the site down.    # BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sale/(.*)$ http://dland.in/kerala-real-estate-sale/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old-folder/(.*)$ /new-folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I changed my .htaccess accordingly but does'nt work. I think I had not clearly mentioned the slug change in my previous question.      

This was the actual previous link in this wordpress site,     

[link]http://dland.in/sale/land-in-madikeri-karnataka-state-india-1750-acre/    

and now the folder name has changed and this is the new link     

[link]http://dland.in/kerala-real-estate-sale/land-in-madikeri-karnataka-state-india-1750-acre/    
  
the second slug (land-in-madikeri-karnataka-state-india-1750-acre) can be any so I want to get a 301 redirect to the new link.    

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SuzyMatts As you can see, it works perfectly fine for me, using your example:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/q0EfW.png  The left window is the HTTP transcript, requesting a couple of different URLs. The right screen is the htaccess file. Works as advertised.

Comment: @JunLin this is my .htaccess content. can you please check what I am doing wrong  # BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sale/(.*)$ http://dland.in/kerala-real-estate-sale/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @SuzyMatts You need to put the 301 redirect rule **above** the ones where you route everything to `index.php`, otherwise nothing gets redirected, because the URI becomes `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes on the content of the htaccess you posted (removed the duplicated rewrite base and moved the sale rule first), try this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sale/(.*)$ dland.in/kerala-real-estate-sale/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```